# How can I change the order life cycle in Magento?

Tags: magento

I’m new to magento and as far as I can see, the order states are labeled as "pending", "processing" and "completed". When customer checks out, then the state becomes "pending", and either invoicing or shipping makes the state "processing", and when both are done, state becomes "completed". Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, I’d like to introduce new **states but not statuses**, I did manage to introduce new statuses when it is in one of the states above, or I could change the labels of the existing states but I want to learn how magento manages the states and how to modify it/add new states. I can modify the core code if required.

So, my question is how do I introduce new states (not statuses) or how do I change/modify the order life-cycle?

I can investigate the source if you tell me which parts of the code is managing the order life-cycle. Any help or clue is appreciated.

PS: I'm using v1.5.1.0 right now.

Answer (score 2):

So in your config.xml you would have something like ...

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <states>
                    <my_state translate="label">
                        <label>My State</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </my_state>
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then whenever you want the state to change you could override the core or add an observer to change the state (*please don't edit the core directly!*) with something like (assuming `$order` is a valid order already loaded and ready to go) ....

```
$order->setState("my_state");
$order->save();
```

which will do the default status for the state. if you want to set a status put that in the second parameter so ..

```
$order->setState("my_state","complete");
$order->save();
```

HTH

Comment: in config.xml, it says these definitions are deprecated and they are storing them in the database. so i changed the database and now i have some other states. but the thing is, the order pipeline is still same, i.e. "checkout->invoice->ship". my question was also about to integrate the new states. do you have any idea about this? can you give me the path where i should look at the implementation?

basically, i'd like to add a button, let's say after shipment it will appear, and will change the state from shipped to received/reviewed etc.

Comment: if you just want to add a button that would cause the state to change then have it go to a url with the order entity_id and load an order model by the entity_id and do what i listed above ... your going to have to give me more details as literally this could reference a lot of things ... you could be adding observers or just creating your own processes that are independent .. its up to you.

Comment: for example, when i create invoice, the state becomes "processing". when i create shipment, i want it to become "shipped". after this step, i need another button to be appear there, which changes the state as "installed". the aim is that, i want to keep track of my device's installers' activities inside magento. when they install, i'll start the service, so there should also be another button to change the state to "ready" from "installed".

Comment: currently, i can do this using statuses, but let's say i need to remove some states instead of adding some other. then using statuses does not work in this case. that's why i want to learn how to change the order pipeline.

i appreciate your help.

Comment: the problem is that what i think you are referring to as the "order pipeline" is spread out over various places. There isn't just one spot were it changes everything at least not that im aware of. So depending on what you want to get rid of then you would need to find that logic and edit it.

Comment: i know it is not "change single source and done" thing, but i couldn't even find somebody trying to change this and eventually successful. that's strange or i want something to do with magento which i shouldn't be using for it normally. anyway, if you -by chance- see some sort of people trying to do the similar thing, please let me know so we can discuss with them together. and thanks anyway for your time.